# Is Object.defineProperty() preferable over setting the constructor directly when inheriting from a base constructor function

Tags: javascript

When subclassing a function constructor, is it preferable to use `defineProperty()` instead of setting the constructor equal to the base class directly? I've seen both and I am a bit confused about the difference between the two (both seem to allow attributes and methods to be inherited, but one is more readable).

For example:

```
function Person(first, last, age, gender, interests) {
    this.name = {
        'first': first,
        'last': last
    };
    this.age = age;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.interests = interests;
}

Person.prototype.greeting = function() {
    console.log(`Hello from ${this.name.first} ${this.name.last} from inside Person!`);
};


function Teacher(first, last, age, gender, interests, subject) {
    Person.call(this, first, last, age, gender, interests);

    this.subject = subject;
}

Teacher.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);

Object.defineProperty(Teacher.prototype, 'constructor', {
    value: Teacher,
    enumerable: false, // so that it does not appear in 'for in' loop
    writable: true
});

// Teacher.prototype.constructor = Person;

let teacher = new Teacher('Bob', 'Smith', 32, 'male', ['music', 'skiing'], 'Math');
teacher.greeting();
console.log(teacher.subject);
```

I've seen this used:

```
Object.defineProperty(Teacher.prototype, 'constructor', {
    value: Teacher,
    enumerable: false, // so that it does not appear in 'for in' loop
    writable: true
});
```

as well as this:

```
Teacher.prototype.constructor = Person;
```

Which is preferable and why?

Comment: There is no "preferable" way. It depends on what you want. `.defineProperty` is for when you want to control the aspects of the property (getter, setter, writeable, enumerable, etc.). Directly creating the property on a prototype is good for when you don't.

Comment: When subclassing a function constructor, it is preferable to use `class` syntax: problem solved :-)

Comment: "*use `defineProperty()` instead of `create()`?*" - it's used **in addition** to `Object.create` - the `create` call is there in both of your examples.  `defineProperty` can be used *instead* of the simple property assignment.

Comment: "*Which is preferable and why?*" - the comment in your code already mentions the purpose of `defineProperty`: *`so that it does not appear in 'for in' loop`*. That's really the only difference. And many (most?) people don't care about enumerating the properties of their instances, so they just go with the simpler (shorter) solution.

Comment: @Bergi my apologies I just edited the title (if it's still not correct please feel free to edit). I didn't mention in my post... but I was wondering about the enumeration part and you also answered that for me

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you are reading it wronge.
`defineProperty()` will add a new Property on a Object which shall be avaiable to that object only, even if the Object was inherited.

Here is a Example

```
    //Empty Object
    const bill = {};
    
    bill.defineProperty(bill, 'total', {
      value: 42,
      writable: false
    });
    
    bill.total= 77;
    // throws an error in strict mode
    
    console.log(bill.total);
    // expected output: 42
```

if you make `writable: true` you can add new values to it
so basically, using defineProperty should be used for creating OR Defining a New Property on Empty/Copied or any other version of Object(s) Individually

Whereas For Create() will create a entierly new Object based on a exisiting Obj with exisiting Properties(basically a xerox copy of the Object).

Here is the example

```
const fetus= {
  isHuman: false,
  printIntroduction: function() {
    console.log(`My name is ${this.name}. Am I human? ${this.isHuman}`);
  }
};
const me = Object.create(fetus);

me.name = 'Indiana'; // "name" is a property set on "me", but not on "person"
me.isHuman = true; // inherited properties can be overwritten

me.printIntroduction();
// expected output: "My name is Indiana. Am I human? true"
```

Here in the create() example i can use define Property on me to set a last name

```
Object.defineProperty(me, 'lastName', {
  value: Jones,
  writable: true
});
```

This way now my `fetus` Obj is different than `me` Obj

Hence, When it comes to Prefrence.. there is none.. it will depend on use case to use case basis. (Ideally whichever works :) ) for that app or function